# How do you serialize Android Intents?

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent

Android Intents have a convenient [toURI()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toUri(int)) method which the API docs seem to indicate is a way to serialize an Intent to a URI, and then later parse it back into an Intent.  Unfortunately, in testing this functionality I found that it does not serialize all extras, just the primitive types (boolean, int, long, float, String).  If an intent specifies any Parcelable or array extras then those will get lost.

Where (if anywhere) is this limitation documented?  Is there some obvious reason for this behavior (I can imagine some difficulties with Parcelables)?  And most importantly, is there a recommended way to serialize and parse Intents?

My current implementation simply writes Intent components (action, categories, data uri, and extras) to a SharedPreferences.  This strategy does not support Parcelables.

Answer (score 7):

> Android Intents have a convenient toURI() method which the API docs seem to indicate is a way to serialize an Intent to a URI, and then later parse it back into an Intent.

Not really.

> Where (if anywhere) is this limitation documented?

I would not have expected extras to be included in the `Uri` at all. The point behind this sort of `Uri` generation would be to show you how to add the `Uri` as a link on a Web site, and you should not need extras for that scenario.

`toURI()` is not serialization.

> And most importantly, is there a recommended way to serialize and parse Intents?

No. In particular, `Parcelable` cannot be serialized, by definition.

> My current implementation simply writes Intent components (action, categories, data uri, and extras) to a SharedPreferences.

That approach is simply bizarre.

Use a database. If you were attacked by a database as a young child and therefore live in abject fear of databases, serialize using JSON, XML, or `Serializable`/`ObjectOutputStream` to a file. Use `SharedPreferences` for user preferences.

> This strategy does not support Parcelables.

Nor should it. Nor can it. `Parcelable` is designed to convert an object graph into a memory block for use in a running device only. It is not a long-term persistence mechanism.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained my situation.  I am attempting to store semi-permanently intents for broadcasts that have been received.  These intents will have actions and extras known only at runtime.  The action and extras are used to start and stop arbitrary services, also known only at runtime.  Rather than building a custom data structure to store the intent data, I figured it would be easier to store the original intent.  From what you are saying, it sounds like you don't know of a better way than using a custom data structure.

Comment: @Alan: You will need a custom data structure. Few, if any, `android.*` classes implement `Serializable`, which is what you would need for full serialization. About the only way I can think of for `Serializable` to work would be for you to create your own subclass, make *it* `Serializable`, and rely upon the `Intent` copy constructor to do the legwork of getting information from an `Intent` into your `Serializable` subclass. For that, I'd just write the stuff to JSON. But, then again, I've never liked `Serializable`.