# How do you store an intent into an SQL database?(Android)

Tags: java, php, android, http, android-intent

Im trying to store an intent from an android app to a database and I'm having some issues converting it into a string and storing it in the database.Its connecting to the database and the id is incrementing.

Ive stored the intents inside the string.xml file like this:

`<string name="key_username">username</string>`

`<string name="key_pet_name">pet_name</string>`

I took the intent from another actvity like this:

```
Intent i = newIntent(Hamster.this,Death.class);                              i.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_username),Username);                     i.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_pet_name), Petname);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(i);
```

And this is the code I'm using to connect to the database:

```
  public class Death extends Activity {

    public static String Petsname,Username ;


    private ImageView dead;
    private Button submit;
    private TextView hamsters_death;
    public static final String TAG = "Death";




    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.death);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Username = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_username));
                String Petname = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_pet_name));


                Log.d(TAG, Username);
                Log.d(TAG,Petname);



                new SummaryAsyncTask().execute(new FormData());

            }
        });


    }
}
class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<FormData, Void, JSONArray> {
    Intent intent;


    public String Username;
    public String Petname;





    public void postData(String Username, String Petname)

    {


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888/Hamster_website/hamster.php");


        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> form_items = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            form_items.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", Username));
            form_items.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Petname", Petname));


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form_items));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  " + e.toString());
        }


    }

    protected JSONArray doInBackground(FormData... params) {
        postData(Username, Petname);
        return null;
    }




}



class FormData {

    public JSONArray PostForm() {


        {

            String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/Hamster_website/hamster.php";


            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                // Signals error in http protocol
                e.printStackTrace();

                //Log Errors Here


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;


            if (httpEntity != null) {
                try {
                    String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                    Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try {

                //JSONArray =

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


                    Log.d("JSON DEBUG", jsonArray.get(i).toString());


                }

            } catch (JSONException jse) {
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jsonArray;


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10818241/2197700) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189475/how-do-you-serialize-android-intents).